# Removing text within an element that is after the first <br>, but before the second <br> on each relevant row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text in a table cell that has 3 text blocks separated by `<br>`. I need to keep the first of these for each time the same row appears in a table.

/* JQuery loop */

```
$('.invoiceTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
title = $("tr.invoiceTableCatalog td").html().split("<br>")[0];
$("tr.invoiceTableCatalog td:first").replaceWith( '<td>'+title+'</td>' );
});
```

/* Javascript loop */

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.invoiceTable > tbody  > tr'), function(tr) {

title = $(".invoiceTableCatalog td").html().split("<br>")[0];
$(".invoiceTableCatalog td:first").replaceWith( '<td>'+title+'</td>' );

});
```

However The first row for the occurrence changes, not the other rows.

Here is the HTML for the row:

```
<tr class="invoiceTableDetail invoiceTableCatalog">
<td class="invoiceTableItem" style="width:40%;" valign="top">
Multibooking discount
<br>This is a multibooking discount for being kind enough to buy lots of courses with us - thanks
<br>(based on -20 Percent of Total Price)
</td>
</tr>
```

I'd have expected that each row would have the content replaced, but no, it is not ;-(

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: `$(this).find('td:first').html...` And `$(this).find('td:first').replaceWith....`

Comment: And while you just want to loop through `tr`s with class `invoiceTableCatalog` so you can use `$('.invoiceTable > tbody  > tr.invoiceTableCatalog').each(function() {`